# Extract pixel values within a selection or region of interest

Tags: imagej

I am struggling to extract individual pixel values from a selection or area of interest using imageJ. I have tried to save the image as a text file, but it is very hard working to find and collect the pixels I am interested in. I have also tried to extract the histogram values from the option "list" however, it put several pixels with in a bin range and I want to extract every single individual value.

Do you know any way to do this?
Any other software suggestions are also welcome.

Many thanks in advance 
:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution form an imageJ mailing list form Nabble. This is a macro that do the trick:

```
//------------------------------------------------ 
Roi.getBounds(rx, ry, width, height); 
row = 0; 

for(y=ry; y<ry+height; y++) { 
    for(x=rx; x<rx+width; x++) { 
        if(Roi.contains(x, y)==1) { 
            setResult("X", row, x); 
            setResult("Y", row, y); 
            setResult("Value", row, getPixel(x, y)); 
            row++; 
        } 
    } 
} 
//------------------------------------------------
```

Credits
CEO: Dr. Jan Brocher

Here the link to the thread

http://imagej.1557.x6.nabble.com/Extracts-individual-pixel-values-from-a-selection-or-RIO-td5020121.html

Comment: There is another option using the function `Save XY Coordinates` that is under `Analyze` -> `Tools`